# Unable to run spark-terasort with spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop1

Tags: maven, hadoop, apache-spark

I am trying to run [spark-terasort](https://github.com/ehiggs/spark-terasort) with spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop1 (pre-built package for hadoop 1.X).

When I try to run spark:

```
./bin/spark-submit --class com.github.ehiggs.spark.terasort.TeraGen  ~/spark-terasort/target/spark-terasort-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar 100G hdfs:///input_terasort
```

I get the error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found class org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext, but interface was expected

This may have to do with different Hadoop versions (between spark and spark-terasort). I have tried playing around with pom.xml (used to compile spark-terasort) but without much success.

**How can I use spark-terasort with spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop1?**

Answer (score 0):

The `spark-terasort` *is* old:

```
  <scala.binary.version>2.10</scala.binary.version>
  <spark.version>1.2.1</spark.version>
```

I am looking into patching it. Will get back..

**Update** I tried with `1.6.0-SNAPSHOT` and TeraGen worked fine.

```
Input size: 1000KB
Total number of records: 10000
Number of output partitions: 2
Number of records/output partition: 5000
===========================================================================
===========================================================================
Number of records written: 10000
```

This was when running against *local* filesystem.  I will look at *real* hdfs in about 12 hours from now.

Comment: Thanks, where do I get the 1.6.0-SNAPSHOT version of spark?

Comment: Oh - you should be fine with 1.6.1 : your version is slightly *newer* than mine.  Basically I need to do more homework to reproduce your issue.  My results to now were provided more as an "fyi" to show that *teragen* does have some hope.